# Get clean ids by regex

Tags: php, regex

i need your help again ;-)

How can i extract ids from given string:

```
",object|1301,object|5419,object|5364,"
```

Can it solved by a regular expression?

Thank for answers

Comment: You just want the numbers?  Why not `/d+`?  Show your expected result.  You want an array right?

Comment: A regex, or a couple of [explode](http://php.net/explode)'s should do the trick.

Comment: You can use `([0-9]+)` to get the numbers from the string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A Regex Method: [Demo](https://3v4l.org/Dim8W)

```
$in = ",object|1301,object|5419,object|5364,";
var_export(preg_split('/\D+/', $in, 0, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY));
```

Output:

```
array (
  0 => '1301',
  1 => '5419',
  2 => '5364',
)
```

---

A non-regex method (there will be many ways to do this):

```
$in=",object|1301,object|5419,object|5364,";
var_export(array_filter(explode(',object|', rtrim($in, ',')), 'strlen'));
```

(same output)

---

A `preg_match_all()` method:

```
$in = ",object|1301,object|5419,object|5364,";
var_export(preg_match_all('/\K\d+/', $in, $out) ? $out[0] : []);
```

(same output)

--

Another non-regex method:

```
$in = ",object|1301,object|5419,object|5364,";
var_export(explode('|', ltrim(str_replace(',object', '', $in), '|')));
```

(same output)

Answer (score 0):

Use the pattern `([0-9]+)` to get the numbers from the string.

Example: https://regex101.com/r/6Unuvt/1/